# Can I use a .vbs VBScript script file on an HTML page? Or how can I replicate in?

Tags: html, vbscript, implementation, hta

I have a VBScript script file saved as a .vbs on my desktop: pastebin.com/Nhj5Rs0j

Can I take this and put it in a HTML file to upload to my website via FTP?

I tried to do this on Internet Explorer and I clicked allow active content. I get done, but with an error on the page (I just realized this).

Can I recreate these events using a .hta or some other programming language?

What can I possibly do to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with VBScript in the browser (IE only, ofcourse), but the script you provided in the pastebin will never work, because it is a script for Windows-based Scripting Host environment that is only executable in the OS itself and not in the web browser.

Comment: Is there some other programming language i can use to recreate these events so other people can use it?

Comment: What events? Your WSH script, just starts an Internet Explorer instance and then quits. That's not very useful at all.

Comment: I'm trying to have a button that when pressed opens a new window.
The new window redirects to specified url, pauses for specified time, then redirects to another specified url, pauses, repeat